# Problem with updating data into SQLite-android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

This is my table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tbl_groupAccount ( \n" +
        "    ID                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT\n" +
        "                               NOT NULL\n" +
        "                               UNIQUE,\n" +
        "    ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAME VARCHAR,\n" +
        "    ACCOUNT_GROUP_TYPE  VARCHAR \n" +
        ");");
```

and I use this to update data into the table

```
public boolean updateAccountGroup(String nameAccountGroup,String groupAccountType, Integer id) {
    boolean result;
    String sql = "UPDATE tbl_groupAccount" +
            " SET ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAME , ACCOUNT_GROUP_TYPE = '" + nameAccountGroup + groupAccountType + "'" +
            "WHERE ID = " + id;

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL(sql);
        database.close();
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I click on the button to update data into the table, nothing happens. And no errors occur. And nothing is updated to the table. Someone can help me. Please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update sql should be like:

```
String sql = "UPDATE tbl_groupAccount" +
                " SET ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAME = '" + nameAccountGroup + "' , ACCOUNT_GROUP_TYPE ='"+ groupAccountType + "'" +
                " WHERE ID = " + id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `UPDATE` statement is wrong.
Also don't concatenate the parameters that you want to pass to the query.
The recommended and safe way to do it is with the method `update()` and `?` placeholders:

```
public boolean updateAccountGroup(String nameAccountGroup,String groupAccountType, Integer id) {
    ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
    c.put("ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAME", nameAccountGroup);
    c.put("ACCOUNT_GROUP_TYPE", groupAccountType);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    boolean result = db.update("tbl_groupAccount", c, "ID = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}) > 0;
    db.close();            
    return result;
}
```

The method `update()` returns the number of affected/updated rows, so if this number is greater than `0` the method `updateAccountGroup()` will return `true`.